# Simple calculator problem

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, serial, calculator

So I am trying to create a calculator program in arduino using this codes.

```
void loop()
{
    char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
    if (keypressed != NO_KEY)
    {
        //Serial.print(keypressed - 48);
        Serial.print(keypressed);

        if(keypressed > 47 && keypressed < 58)
        {
              if(!mySwitch)
              {
                  num1 = (num1*10) + (keypressed - 48);
              }else{
                  num2 = (num2*10) + (keypressed - 48);
              }
         }

         if(keypressed == 61)
         {
             answer = num1 + num2;
             Serial.println(answer);    
             num1 = 0;
             num2 = 0;
             mySwitch = false;
         }else if (keypressed == 43)
         {
             mySwitch = true;
         }
    }
}
```

This code is for adding the numbers. I do a nested loop

```
if(keypressed == 61)
{
    if(keypressed == 43){
        answer = num1 + num2;
        Serial.println(answer);    
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        mySwitch = false;
    }else if (keypressed == 43){
        mySwitch = true;
    }

    if(keypressed == 45){
        answer = num1 - num2;
        Serial.println(answer);    
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        mySwitch = false;
    }else if (keypressed == 45){
        mySwitch = true;
    }
}
```

it will only accepts the value and not compute it after pressing the "="sign
btw "61", "43", "45" is the ASCII value of "=", "+", "-"

Comment: Could you properly indent your code, please, and tell us what the various values of `keypressed` mean.

Comment: And maybe generally reduce your problem. You will probably find your mistake in doing so.

Comment: They're ASCII character values; e.g., '0' through '9' and 'A';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood what you are trying to do (subtraction  when '-' is pressed and addition when '+' is pressed), use the following:

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte numRows = 4; //number of rows on the keypad
const byte numCols = 4; //number of columns on the keypad

//keymap defines the key pressed according to the row and columns just as appears on        the keypad
char keymap[numRows][numCols] =
{
    {'1', '2', '3', '+'},
    {'4', '5', '6', '-'},
    {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
    {' ', '0', '=', 'D'}
};

//Code that shows the the keypad connections to the arduino terminals
byte rowPins[numRows] = {11, 10, 9, 8}; //Rows 0 to 3
byte colPins[numCols] = {7, 6, 5, 4}; //Columns 0 to 3

//initializes an instance of the Keypad class
Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

long num1, num2, answer;
boolean mySwitch = false;
boolean do_subtraction_flag = false;  // when true we will apply subtraction

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
}

//If key is pressed, this key is stored in 'keypressed' variable
//If key is not equal to 'NO_KEY', then this key is printed out
//if count=17, then count is reset back to 0 (this means no key is pressed during the   whole keypad scan process


void loop()
{
    char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();

    if(keypressed != NO_KEY)
    {

        //Serial.print(keypressed - 48);
        Serial.print(keypressed);

        if(keypressed > 47 && keypressed < 58)  // is between '0' and '9'
        {
            if(!mySwitch)
            {
                num1 = (num1 * 10) + (keypressed - 48);
            }
            else
            {
                num2 = (num2 * 10) + (keypressed - 48);
            }
        }

        if(keypressed == '=')
        {
            if(do_subtraction_flag)  // we want to subtract the numbers
            {
                answer = num1 - num2;
            }
            else  // we want to add the numbers
            {
                answer = num1 + num2;
            }

            Serial.println(answer);
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 0;
            mySwitch = false;
            do_subtraction_flag = false;
        }
        else if(keypressed == '+')
        {
            mySwitch = true;
        }
        else if(keypressed == '-')
        {
            mySwitch = true;
            do_subtraction_flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have added a flag Boolean variable named `do_subtraction_flag`
The flag is set depending on the button used, false for addition and true for subtraction.
Its value is used when '=' is pressed to conditionally execute the code that either subtracts num2 from num1 or adds them.

Note that I have replaced `keypressed == 61` with `keypressed == '='`
and `keypressed == 43` with `keypressed == '+'`
It is much easier to read the code this way.

Comment: you got what im trying to do , but when i tried you code theres an error _expected primary-expression before 'if'_ in         `if(keypressed > 47 && keypressed < 58)  // is between '0' and '9'`

Comment: @NewInEverything Yes, sorry there were two ++ characters inserted when I tried to zoom my editor (in the line just before the error), they should be removed.

Comment: your right. How about clearing the screen. I search over the net and found `Serial.print(27,BYTE);   //Print "esc"
  Serial.print("[2J");` but some said it doesnt work anymore. and also deleting a single character.

Comment: @NewInEverything Try the solutions provided [Clearing the terminal screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105666/clearing-the-terminal-screen)

Comment: I tried that. but I am using a 4x20 display to show the output. even I tried that the display will only go at the bottom most line of my display.

Comment: @NewInEverything The display has a clear command, I'm not sure how to call it, read the library manual